# Why do I need typings to work with typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've read: [How to setup Material-UI for React with Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186500/how-to-setup-material-ui-for-react-with-typescript)

I'm completely new to typescript and thought that typescript is a superset of normal javascript. If so why do I have to do: `typings install dt~material-ui --global --save` in order to work with material-ui? Why does my materila-ui modules do not load without?

`ERROR in ./source/scripts/components/app.tsx
(4,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'material-ui/AppBar'.`

Comment: Typescript is needed because the library is written in Typescript...? It has to be compiled to Javascript

Comment: maybe you should spend some time reading about Typescript? :)

Comment: also, if your react project doesn't use typescript already you're not going to need it.

Comment: @cricket_007 I do not think that material-ui is written in typescript

Comment: @toskv Your first comment is not really helpfull. Well your seconds also not, sry ;) Do you have any sources I could dig into regarding typings?

Comment: Are you writing your project in TypeScript? If so and you're using the material-ui then you need to install (or write your own) type declarations (or typings) for every Javascript library you're using in order for the typescript compiler to perform type checking. I suggest you read [the typescript docs](http://typescriptlang.com).

Comment: @jebar8 But can't I use a module without type checking. Like a normal javascript module?

Comment: @velop see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you writing your project in TypeScript? If so and you're using the material-ui then you need to install (or write your own) type declarations (or typings) for every Javascript library you're using in order for the typescript compiler to perform type checking. I suggest you read [the typescript docs](http://typescriptlang.com).

Every module must have type declarations. If you really don't want to install them then one you can [write your own](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html) and use the `any` keyword to skip type checking.

Comment: It's not that I don't like them. But that all following modules I installed via npm (like https://github.com/taoyuan/reactee) do not have any type declarations yet. And writting them all would be really tedious.

Comment: @velop if you use the `any` keyword then your typings will basically be one line per module. I would show you an example but I'm away from my computer.

Comment: @velop This might be relevant for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834121/typescript-what-to-do-if-a-typings-or-tsd-is-not-available